# NPC not moving to the target location

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minecraft, bukkit, minecraft-forge

I am using citizensAPI to spawn and manipulate NPC. The code is as follows.

I am trying to find the nearest block of type JUNGLE_WOOD in the radius of 20.

```
package org.mineacademy.orion.npctest;

import net.citizensnpcs.api.CitizensAPI;
import net.citizensnpcs.api.ai.PathStrategy;
import net.citizensnpcs.api.hpastar.Tile;
import net.citizensnpcs.api.npc.NPC;
import net.citizensnpcs.npc.ai.AStarNavigationStrategy;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.mineacademy.fo.command.SimpleCommand;

public class BlockFinder extends SimpleCommand {

    public BlockFinder(){
        super("finder");
    }

    public void onCommand() {
        checkConsole();

        NPC npc= CitizensAPI.getNPCRegistry().createNPC(EntityType.VILLAGER,"cutter");
        Player player=getPlayer();
        npc.spawn(player.getTargetBlock(null, 5).getLocation().add(3, 3, 0));

        //add location and setTarget to that location.

        Location finalLoc=newLocation(npc,player);
        npc.setProtected(false);
        npc.faceLocation(finalLoc);
        npc.getNavigator().setTarget(finalLoc);


    }

    public Location newLocation(NPC npc, Player player) {
        double r =25;
        double x=npc.getEntity().getLocation().getX();
        double y=npc.getEntity().getLocation().getY();
        double z=npc.getEntity().getLocation().getZ();
        int minx=(int)(x-r);
        int miny=(int)(y-r);
        int minz=(int)(z-r);
        int maxx=(int)(x+r);
        int maxy=(int)(y+r);
        int maxz=(int)(z+r);
        Location nloc=new Location(npc.getEntity().getWorld(),x,y,z);
        for(int rx=minx;rx<=maxx;rx++) {
            for (int ry = miny; ry <= maxy; ry++) {
                for (int rz = minz; rz <= maxz; rz++) {
                    Block block = player.getWorld().getBlockAt(rx, ry, rz);
                    if (block.getType() == Material.JUNGLE_WOOD) {
                        nloc.setX(rx);
                        nloc.setY(ry);
                        nloc.setZ(rz);
                        return nloc;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nloc;
    }

}
```

The NPC spawns properly but sometimes it does not move at all, and otherwise it spins or just moves a couple of meters and stops.
Does anyone know any fix so that I am able to move the NPC along a path to that block?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check if the NPC exists : `NPC.isSpawned()` - boolean

Then, you should trigger this part after the NPCSpawnEvent (https://jd.citizensnpcs.co/net/citizensnpcs/api/event/NPCSpawnEvent.html) :

```
        Location finalLoc=newLocation(npc,player);
        npc.setProtected(false);
        npc.faceLocation(finalLoc);
        npc.getNavigator().setTarget(finalLoc);
```

By the way, you can google it : https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/citizens-api-problem-walking-npc.365712/

I found this, really useful.